# What are the new type qualifiers introduced with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) introduces some new type qualifiers. I've seen `__strong` and `__weak`, but what do they do?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`__strong` means that on assignment, the rvalue of the expression will be retained and stored into the lvalue using primitive semantics. (To deallocate such an object, all you must do is assign it `nil`, the previously referenced object will be released, `nil` will be retained, which effectively does nothing and it's peaches and cream.)

`__unsafe_unretained` and `__weak` are similar in the sense that the address of the rvalue will be assigned to the lvalue, but if you use the `__weak` qualifier, this operation is guaranteed to be atomic and subject to some different semantics. One of these are that if the object that is being assigned is currently undergoing deallocation, then the assignment will evaluate to `nil` and that will then be atomically stored back in to the lvalue of the expression. Hence the wording `__unsafe_unretained`, because that operation is indeed unsafe and unretained.

`__autoreleasing` is like `__strong` except it has one caveat: The retained object is pushed onto the current autorelease pool, so you can for example obtain temporary ownership of an object to remove it from a collection and then return it back to the caller. There are other uses for this, but they mostly have to do with obtaining temporary ownership of an object.

These behaviors also present themselves in the corresponding property modifiers (`strong`, `unsafe_unretained` and `weak`).

See the [Clang Automatic Reference Counting Technical Specification](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

**EDIT:** For those not targeting iOS 5 and therefore unable to reap the benefits of `__weak`, [Mike Ash wrote a superb article](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) (and implementation) on zeroing weak references which you can use instead.

Comment: How do you make the `unsafe__unretain` object safer? I mean, if it's not turned to `nil` automatically by the compiler then how should we be handling that dangling object?

Comment: If I'm not wrong `__weak` is not available in later iOS versions, then in that case how am I going to make `unsafe__unretain` object safer, which is not set to `nil` automatically?

Answer (score 4):

Strong tells ARC to retain the property.

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSObject *object;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSObject *object;
```

Weak is essentially assign, a unretained property. Except the when the object is deallocated the weak pointer is automatically set to nil.

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSObject *object;
@property (assign,nonatomic) NSObject *object;
```

Weak is only available on iOS 4.3 and up. If you want to target iOS 4.2 you need to use unsafe_unretained, that will work exactly like assign used to.

Comment: On Mac OS X, `weak` is only available since Lion; your iOS 4.2 advice goes for Snow Leopard as well.

Comment: @NJones, I do have a question though. How on earth can `weak` be `nonatomic`? `weak` *by definition* is `atomic`.

Comment: @JacobRelkin. That's a good question. I would assume that nonatomic is belied by the weak modifier. But that is how it's done; Just to check I started a new Xcode project, added a label, and then connected an outlet sure enough it gave me '@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;'.

Answer (score 1):

The type qualifiers are `__autoreleasing`, `__strong`, `__unsafe_unretained`, and `__weak`.  The property modifiers are `strong`, `unsafe_unretained`, and `weak`.

Have a look at [section 4 of *Automatic Reference Counting*](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership) in the LLVM/Clang documentation.