# Objective-c: Reference to ivar persistent? Good idea?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, reference

I have a situation where I'm keeping references to ivars which need to be persistent.  In one object, I have an array of pointers to ivars in another object, which are used over the entire lifetime of the program.  In other words, I'm not just passing a reference to retrieve a value -- I'm keeping the pointers around.

Is this a valid?  Is it possible that the ivars might move?  Are there cases where objects instantiated objects are moved around at runtime unbeknownst to the program?  Or, do objects stay exactly where they are created.  If the later is the case, is there any reason not to use references the way I am?

I'm using ARC.

Note:  This probably wasn't a good way to design this to begin with, but... it's all done and working 99%!  (except for a nasty crash which reboots the entire phone... )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects and their instance variables don't move once created.  However, you also need to keep a strong reference to the object that holds the ivar.  Otherwise, the object might be deallocated, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Note that it is generally a very bad idea to have pointers to another object's insntance variables.

Comment: Ok, this is a basic question, but -- what's a "strong reference?"

Comment: Read the answers to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949460/what-are-the-new-type-qualifiers-introduced-with-arc

Answer (score 0):

While there's no technical problem with accessing the ivars from outside (as rob stated) there's still the architectural design to consider: The approach you've taken breaks encapsulation. Additionally it is very uncommon for Objective-C.

So regarding maintainability of your code I would recommend to refactor the code. In Objective-C there's no `friend` declaration as in C++, so it's unusual to access ivars from outside the declaring class.

Comment: Functionally, one thing needs to keep a reference to another thing through one level of indirection. (The meta-function of the program -- ironically -- a user-programmable system which uses the one-thing-referencing-another paradigm) So, there's no good way to pass values around.  In that case, what's the correct way to pass a "reference?"

Comment: That's not really enough information to make a good suggestion but if you want to access a list of (public) properties of one object, there's KVC.

Comment: It's an animation system, similar to ones used in 3D graphics software (e.g. Houdini or Maya).  You have a chain of objects which process geometry data as it flows along.  The objects have configuration parameters.  The trick is that the parameters can change over time (are animated), and are themselves generated by non-trivial, time-dependent objects.  They are connected by giving the parameter-generating object a reference to the ivar in the geometry-processing object which represents that parameter.  And all of it is dynamic == no assumptions about the connectivity.

Comment: If the parameters for an object can change at runtime then you might want to look at using a NSMutableDictionary as an ivar/property. This way you can add/delete key/value pairs at will.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say an object of class A wants to access the ivars of an object of class B persistently  (in your example).

What you normally do is create a property (with the `strong` annotation, like `@property (strong) ClassB *myBVar`) in class A to reference an object of class B.
If you want to set or read B's properties you use the dot notation or call the getter/setter methods:

```
myBVar.name = @"Jim";
NSLog(@"Name:%@",myBVar.name);

[myBVar setName:@"Jim"];
NSLog(@"Name:%@",[myBVar name]);
```

You never call a ivar directly as it's implementation might change.

Comment: I realized I left out a really important bit: Both class A and B are instantiated at runtime.  And both can have different and varying numbers and types of parameters.  When I tried to pass references to objects around, the code became convoluted and made the compiler unhappy.  I threw up my hands and figured I'd go with old-school pointers.   So, the question is: how do you "pass by reference" when both objects are anonymous and have different properties, all of which are determined at runtime?

Comment: Objects (instances of a class) are usually created at runtime. When you create and init a new object variable you already create a reference to the object (like `ClassA *myVariable = [ClassA new]`). I don't understand the anonymous part. Can you show a code sample that failed?